# Does the compiler insert typecast when assign subclass to superclass in java?

Tags: java, variable-assignment

I have read effective java chapter 5 generics.

"When you use generics collection instead of raw types, the compiler inserts invisible casts for you and guarantees that..."

So here is my question.

Say we have a Cat class and an Animal class.

```
Class Animal{}

Class Cat extends Animal{}
```

We can do this:

```
Animal animal=new Cat();
```

**Does the compiler inserts a typecast like**:

```
Animal animal=(Animal)(new Cat());?
```

Because I think the cat and animal they have different kinds of references.

Comment: How does your question apply to generics? There are no generics in the snippet you're referring to.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That is where I got this idea. I think they have sth in common?

Comment: The quote explicitly refers to generics, but the code you posted doesn't have any. So what is the relation? What do you think they have in common? Are you asking me if you think they have something in common?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  In generics, the compiler insert invisible casts.So I wonder if it happens when we assign subclass to superclass. And I think generics has lots of subclass and superclass issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the compiler inserts a typecast like:

No. `Cat` is a subtype of `Animal`. You can assign a value of type `Cat` to a variable (or bind it to a parameter) of type `Animal` through [widening reference conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5).

> A widening reference conversion exists from any reference type `S` to
>   any reference type `T`, provided `S` is a subtype (§4.10) of `T`.

There are no casts involved or necessary. Generics are unrelated.